# Solve Dining Philosophers Problem Using pthreads, mutex locks, and condition variables

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable, dining-philosopher

**I'm trying to implement the dining philosophers problem in C using pthreads, mutex locks, and condition variables.**

- It needs to take a command line argument to specify how long the program should run. I have to use the sleep function to accomplish this.
- Each philosopher can eat a maximum of 10 meals. Once they reach 10 meals the pthread should terminate.
- At the end of the set amount of time, the pthreads need to terminate, and the number of meals each philosopher ate should be printed.

**I'm having a few problems with the output:**

1. Making the main function sleep for the number of seconds entered on the command line doesn't seem to be making the output different.
2. The majority of the philosophers are starving on most executions of the program.
3. When I print out when a philosopher is thinking or eating, a 'philosopher 5' is appearing even though there should only be philosophers 0-4.

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Function declarations
void *pickup_forks(void * philosopher_number);
void *return_forks(void * philosopher_number);
void test(int philosopher_number);
int left_neighbor(int philosopher_number);
int right_neighbor(int philosopher_number);
double think_eat_time(void);
void think(double think_time);
void eat(double eat_time);

//Constants to be used in the program.
#define PHILOSOPHER_NUM 5
#define MAX_MEALS 10
#define MAX_THINK_EAT_SEC 3

//States of philosophers.
enum {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING} state[PHILOSOPHER_NUM];

//Array to hold the thread identifiers.
pthread_t philos_thread_ids[PHILOSOPHER_NUM];

//Mutex lock.
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

//Condition variables.
pthread_cond_t cond_vars[PHILOSOPHER_NUM];

//Array to hold the number of meals eaten for each philosopher.
int meals_eaten[PHILOSOPHER_NUM];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Ensure correct number of command line arguments.
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Please ensure that the command line argument 'run_time' is passed.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //Set command line argument value to variable run_time;
        double run_time = atof(argv[1]);

        //Initialize arrays.
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHER_NUM; i++)
        {
            state[i] = THINKING;
            pthread_cond_init(&cond_vars[i], NULL);
            meals_eaten[i] = 0;
        }


        //Initialize the mutex lock.
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

        //Join the threads.
        for(i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHER_NUM; i++)
        {
            pthread_join(philos_thread_ids[i], NULL);
        }

        //Create threads for the philosophers.
        for(i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHER_NUM; i++)
        {
            pthread_create(&philos_thread_ids[i], NULL, pickup_forks, (void *)&i);
        }

        sleep(run_time);

        for(i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHER_NUM; i++)
        {
            pthread_cancel(philos_thread_ids[i]);
        }

        //Print the number of meals that each philosopher ate.
        for(i = 0; i < PHILOSOPHER_NUM; i++)
        {
            printf("Philosopher %d: %d meals\n", i, meals_eaten[i]);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

void *pickup_forks(void * philosopher_number)
{
    int loop_iterations = 0;
    int pnum = *(int *)philosopher_number;

    while(meals_eaten[pnum] < MAX_MEALS)
    {
        printf("Philosoper %d is thinking.\n", pnum);
        think(think_eat_time());

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        state[pnum] = HUNGRY;
        test(pnum);

        while(state[pnum] != EATING)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_vars[pnum], &mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        (meals_eaten[pnum])++;

        printf("Philosoper %d is eating meal %d.\n", pnum, meals_eaten[pnum]);
        eat(think_eat_time());

        return_forks((philosopher_number));

        loop_iterations++;
    }
}

void *return_forks(void * philosopher_number)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    int pnum = *(int *)philosopher_number;

    state[pnum] = THINKING;

    test(left_neighbor(pnum));
    test(right_neighbor(pnum));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int left_neighbor(int philosopher_number)
{
    return ((philosopher_number + (PHILOSOPHER_NUM - 1)) % 5);
}

int right_neighbor(int philosopher_number)
{
    return ((philosopher_number + 1) % 5);
}

void test(int philosopher_number)
{
    if((state[left_neighbor(philosopher_number)] != EATING) && 
        (state[philosopher_number] == HUNGRY) &&
        (state[right_neighbor(philosopher_number)] != EATING))
    {
        state[philosopher_number] = EATING;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_vars[philosopher_number]);
    }
}

double think_eat_time(void)
{
    return ((double)rand() * (MAX_THINK_EAT_SEC - 1)) / (double)RAND_MAX + 1;
}

void think(double think_time)
{
    sleep(think_time);
}

void eat(double eat_time)
{
    sleep(eat_time);
}
```

**Here is an output using 10 seconds:**

```
~$ gcc dining_philos.c -o dp -lpthread
~$ ./dp 10
Philosoper 1 is thinking.
Philosoper 2 is thinking.
Philosoper 3 is thinking.
Philosoper 4 is thinking.
Philosoper 5 is thinking.
Philosoper 2 is eating meal 1.
Philosoper 4 is eating meal 1.
Philosoper 2 is thinking.
Philosoper 4 is thinking.
Philosoper 2 is eating meal 2.
Philosoper 4 is eating meal 4.
Philosoper 4 is thinking.
Philosoper 2 is thinking.
Philosoper 2 is eating meal 3.
Philosoper 4 is eating meal 5.
Philosoper 2 is thinking.
Philosoper 4 is thinking.

Philosopher 0: 2 meals
Philosopher 1: 0 meals
Philosopher 2: 3 meals
Philosopher 3: 0 meals
Philosopher 4: 5 meals
```

**I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pthread_create passes a pointer as its last argument.  That pointer must be valid at the time the thread is run, not just when it is created.  You are using a pointer to the loop variable i, which has evaporated.

Also not sure why you are calling pthread_join before pthread_create, but I expect it is returning errors (which you aren't checking).

Comment: Ok. I created another array that holds the philosopher numbers and passed the ith index of that array for philosopher i in pthread_create. That seems to have done the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I don’t know what that means

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late but for later references 3. problem occurs because you are losing the data when creating philosophers. Try making array and send arrays data address and problem solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).